# Delete from database php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a delete from database..So, I have:

```
  <?php
 include('createdb.php');
 if(!empty ($_POST['tribuna']))
 {
  $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tb_tribuna WHERE id = '".$_POST['tribuna']."';"); 
header("Location:index.php?a=buy"); //redirect
exit;
    }
   ?>
  <form id="formid" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"> 
       <label>Tribuna :</label> <select name="tribuna" class="tribuna">
       <option selected="selected">-Select-</option>
            <?php
   $sql=mysql_query("select id,tribune_number from tb_tribuna ");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
      $id=$row['id'];
    $tribune_number=$row['tribune_number'];
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$tribune_number.'</option>';
     } ?>
   </select><br/><br/>
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
  </form>
```

When I push on submit nothing happens...
I want that when I select an option and when I press delete to delete from the database row...
Help plizzz friends..

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` output after posting your data? You're not escaping it so that may be your problem

Comment: This example is very easy to inject. You should be using prepared statements or at least use `mysql_real_escape()`. (Although even that isn't 100% safe). I recommend PDO.

Comment: Where is your connect, select db commands and error output ?

Comment: What exactly Jeroen? I don't understand...can you give me an example?

Comment: PLIZZZZZZZZZ HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "createdb.php" has the correct database connection information:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("$host","$db_uid","$db_pwd");
mysql_select_db("$db", $conn);
```

make your delete function look like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tb_tribuna WHERE id = '$_POST[tribuna]' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to pass the db connection to mysql_query.

And add "or die mysql_error()" to your mysql statements so that when something doesn't work, you get an error message that helps point you to where the problem is.

Comment: @user2993914 select my answer as the answer to your question